# Apache Camel: setProperty and Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, apache-camel

I have the following Camel route:

```
<route id="myroute">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />

    <!-- Set a new property on the exchange. -->
    <to uri="bean:propSetter?method=setProp" />

    <to uri="direct:fizz" />
</route>
```

My `PropSetter` bean:

```
public class PropSetter {
    // Add new "buzz" ArrayList<Long> to the exchange.
    public void setProp(Exchange exchange) {
        exchange.setProperty("buzz", new ArrayList<Long>());
    }
}
```

**I would like to rewrite this without a Java bean and instead use Camel's `<setProperty/>` element.** The only thing I can *think* of is to use the built-in Groovy expression:

```
<route id="myroute">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=10" />

    <!-- Set a new property on the exchange. -->
    <setProperty propertyName="buzz">
        <groovy>new ArrayList&lt;Long&gt;();</groovy>
    </setProperty>

    <to uri="direct:fizz" />
</route>
```

But this does not seem to work. So how can I use XML to set a new `ArrayList<Long>` on the exchange called `buzz`?

Comment: What do you mean by _"does not seem to work"_?

Comment: you could refer a bean and inside that bean you could assign a list.

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - although I can't decipher whether you need me to clarify the extent of the error I'm seeing, or if you think it *should* work and don't see why it doesn't... do you mind elaborating a bit? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Define a list using Spring's util namespace as :

```
<util:list id="myList" value-type="java.lang.String">
</util:list>
```

Then using the simple language you can access the bean and set in an exchange property

```
<camel:setProperty propertyName="buzz">
  <camel:simple>${bean:myList}</camel:simple>
</camel:setProperty>
```

Comment: You should likely set scope="prototype" on the util:list so a new list is created, otherwise the same shared instance is used